# how to use an instantiated object by its string name in java?

Tags: java, string, swing, object

I'm writing a swing application in java and I have 10 jPanel with 10 jCheckBox in each one. The names of the jPanels are jPanel1, jPanel2, etc; and the names of the jCheckBox in jPanel1 are jCheckBox1_1, jCheckBox1_2, jCheckBox1_3, etc, and similar for the others jPanels. In a moment I need to know which of those jcheckboxes have been checked by the user so I do this

```
    boolean[] selected=new boolean[100];

    for(int i=0; i<selected.length; i++)
        selected[i]=false;

    if(jPanel1.jCheckBox1_1.isSelected())
        selected[0]=true;
    if(jPanel1.jCheckBox1_2.isSelected())
        selected[1]=true;
    if(jPanel1.jCheckBox1_3.isSelected())
        selected[2]=true;
```

and continue with the rest

I should do this way because I use the jCheckBoxes (for seeing if they are checked) in a jFrame, not in their jPanels. The problem is that I have to write a lot of repetitive code, and I think that is not intelligent. So I wonder if I can "recover" those objects and use them by their String names. For example:

```
String[] name=new String[100];
JCheckBox[] checkbox=new JCheckBox[name.length];
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    int num_panel=i/10+1;
    name[i]="jPanel"+num_panel+".jCheckBox"+num_panel+"_"+(i%10+1);
}
//and now use those names to ask if those jcheckBoxes are checked
boolean[] selected=new boolean[100];
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
if(name[i].isSelected()) //but this isn't right because its a String, not a jCheckBox
    selected[i]=true;
else
    selected[i]=false;
}
```

So I would like to know if you know any way how I can use those jCheckBoxes by their string name. I know that I could have created them programatically as an array and everything would be easier, but other problem is that because its a swing gui, it's so hard to design them programatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An object does not have a name. Fields, local variable, method parameters have names but they are not all accessible. Also, you cannot have dynamically created variable names in Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Unless you use reflection.

Comment: @Howard Which part of my comment are you referring to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Fields and methods are accessible by their names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I mean that I could have created the jCheckBoxes as an array and add them to a jPanel, but I don't want to do that because the swing design would be so complex. So, is there any way to refer an object by just its string name?

Comment: As I said, an object does not have a name. A field has a name and you can use reflection to access it but that's even worse design than an array.

Comment: Actually a component has a name which can be set. Although in order to find the component you'd have to loop over all again.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

- First option, attach actionListeners to each checkbox to report to the control of the application that the box was checked when it happens. (Or Unchecked).
- Second option, modify your attempt to use an array of checkboxes and just use that array directly to reference the checkbox instead of a second array of Strings.

Comment: so it means that there is no way to use an object by its string name? my idea is to make more simple the code, and I think your first solution will write more repetitive code. And the second solution is similar, I mean that it's necessary to write a lot of repetitive code. Thanks anyway

Comment: Both, solutions should not be implemented with repetitive code.  You would use a loop to setup the ActionListeners and to traverse the array of checkboxes.

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that I can't refer to my original jcheckBoxes since they are not an array (jcheckBox1_1, jcheckBox1_2, etc), so I could refer to them if there would be any way to refer an object only by its name in a String, because in a String array I can programatically get the names of the objects (jCheckBoxes). Is there any way? And if you solution really works but I don't understand it, would you mind giving me a sample code?